# I can't download previous versions of prebid.js

Tags: prebid.js

I can't download previous versions of prebid.js.

I want prebid.js of 2.XX.X, but it is not on the download site.

If you do the following curl command

```
curl -o prebid2.44.7.js -X POST -d "modules%5B%5D=33acrossBidAdapter&modules%5B%5D=adgenerationBidAdapter&modules%5B%5D=ajaBidAdapter&modules%5B%5D=aolBidAdapter&modules%5B%5D=appnexusBidAdapter&modules%5B%5D=audienceNetworkBidAdapter&modules%5B%5D=criteoBidAdapter&modules%5B%5D=logicadBidAdapter&modules%5B%5D=microadBidAdapter&modules%5B%5D=aolBidAdapter&modules%5B%5D=aolBidAdapter&modules%5B%5D=open8BidAdapter&modules%5B%5D=openxBidAdapter&modules%5B%5D=openxoutstreamBidAdapter&modules%5B%5D=pubmaticBidAdapter&modules%5B%5D=rtbhouseBidAdapter&modules%5B%5D=rubiconBidAdapter&modules%5B%5D=yieldoneBidAdapter&modules%5B%5D=currency&modules%5B%5D=dfpAdServerVideo&modules%5B%5D=yieldoneAnalyticsAdapter&version=2.44.7" https://js-download.prebid.org/download
```

"Prebid file not built properly" is displayed.

I don't know the cause.

Answer (score 0):

It was possible to build by the method below.

```
curl -LO https://github.com/prebid/Prebid.js/archive/2.44.7.tar.gz
tar zxvf 2.44.7.tar.gz
cd Prebid.js-2.44.7
npm install
gulp build --modules=XXXXXXXX,YYYYYYYY
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how that was actually working before, but what I would do is:

1. Install the prebid library from source: https://github.com/prebid/Prebid.js
2. Use `git checkout tags/2.44.7`
3. Build the library using the docs in the prebid readme